# Display data containing accented character from string using utf-8 encoding in Java

Tags: java, html, unicode, character-encoding, opensymphony

Hi everyone I am creating a HTML table in Java and sending it to Symphony bot UI.
While creating HTML table I am getting some text from database which has latin word and those are not showing properly on Symphony UI which uses HTML 5.

```
String input = "Montañes";
byte[] ipBytes = input .getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
 input = new String(ipBytes , "UTF-8");
String output = <table><tr><td>input</td><tr></table>
```

By doing above encoding I am not  able to see correct result. In symphony UI I am seeing below
HTML table output.
Monta?es

Please suggest how I can show correct value in html table of Symphony UI.

Comment: Could you clarify why you are converting your string to a byte array (and then back again)? Also, why use ISO-8859-1 during that process? Those steps are causing your problem in the above code.

Comment: @andrewjames Earlier I have not used byte array but while getting error in UI I have used it to convert ISO-8859-1 character to utf-8. If I will not use that piece of code I am getting same response output

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - something which represents the actual code and HTML - the relevant parts? Also the title of the question is perhaps misleading - you are not asking to "escape Latin characters...", but rather to "display data containing accented characters..." or something like that. There are many such questions already on SO, with many great answers. What have you already looked at, and tried?